# Arguments object not working on Underscore first type function

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

For an exercise, I have to reproduce the first function from the Underscore.js library.

The code I wrote passes all the tests, except "should work on an arguments object".

I passed these tests:

- should return an array with the first n elements of the array
- should return an array with the first element if n is not a number, is zero, or
  negative
- should return the entire array if n is > length
- should return an empty array if array is not an array

I failed this test: **should work on an arguments object**

```js
_.first = function (array, n) {
  let arr = [];
  if (!Array.isArray(array)) {
    return [];
  } else if (isNaN(n) || n == null || n <= 0) {
    return [array[0]];
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < n && i < array.length; i++) {
      arr.push(array[i]);
    }
  }
  return arr;
};
```

I would be happy to get some guidance to understand why I am failing to pass the arguments object test. Thanks!

Edit: the solution to my problem:

```js
function (array, n) {
  let arr = [];
  if (
    !(
      Array.isArray(array) ||
      Object.prototype.toString.call(array) === "[object Arguments]"
    )
  ) {
    return [];
  }
  if (isNaN(n) || n == null || n <= 0) {
    return [array[0]];
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < n && i < array.length; i++) {
      arr.push(array[i]);
    }
  }
  return arr;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your `first` function is in your base case wherein you're testing `Array.isArray()`. The `args` object is ***[`array-like`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)*** and not `array`. So you've to factor in that case as well. You can check if the `input` is an instance of arguments. Something like:

```js
function isArrayLike(obj) {
  // Check if the input is an array or an arguments object
  return Array.isArray(obj) || Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Arguments]';
}

_.first = function (array, n) {
  let arr = [];
  
  // Check if the input has a length property
  if (!isArrayLike(array)) {
    return [];
  }
// ...rest
};
```

```js
const _ = {};

function isArrayLike(obj) {
  return Array.isArray(obj) || Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Arguments]';
}

_.first = function(array, n) {
  let arr = [];

  if (!isArrayLike(array)) {
    return [];
  } else if (isNaN(n) || n == null || n <= 0) {
    return [array[0]];
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < n && i < array.length; i++) {
      arr.push(array[i]);
    }
  }

  return arr;
};

function testFirstWithArgs() {
  function testFunc() {
    const result = _.first(arguments, 2);
    return result;
  }

  const expected = [1, 2];
  const actual = testFunc(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

  if (JSON.stringify(actual) === JSON.stringify(expected)) {
    console.log("PASS");
  } else {
    console.log("FAIL");
  }
}

testFirstWithArgs();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem with this solution, is that it fails the test "should return an empty array if array is not an array". Even when adding ` if (!Array.isArray(array)) {
    return [];
  }`to your code snippet I get again "should work on an arguments object".

Comment: @Detla888, I have updated the code. Please take a look and let me know if it works

Comment: thanks. It works. I just made a small change to have your solution within my function (see my edited post).